# How to use multiple elements in JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json

I need my JSON output in this format.

```
{ "DDA":{
            "CustomerId":"String content", 
            "Login":{ 
                      "Password":"String content",
                     "Username":"String content" 
                     },
             "NodeID":"String content" 
           }
 }
```

This is my java class.

```
package com.dvs.request;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.dvs.support.Login;
import com.dvs.support.DDA;

@XmlRootElement(name="DDA")
@XmlType(name = "Login", propOrder = {"DDA","Login"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class LoginRequest {
private DDA dda;
private Login login;
private String CustomerId;
private String nodeID;

@XmlElement
public DDA getDda() {
return dda;
}
public void setDda(DDA dda) {
this.dda = dda;
}

@XmlAttribute
public String getCustomerId() {
return CustomerId;
}
public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
CustomerId = customerId;
}

@XmlAttribute
public String getNodeID() {
return nodeID;
}
public void setNodeID(String nodeID) {
this.nodeID = nodeID;
}

}
```

What should I do with username and password fields and how to get them as in the format I want? I tried with putting username and password in different class but I am getting "illegal annotation exception".

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
mainJsonObject = new JsonObject();
ddaObject = new JsonObject();
mainJsonObject.add("DDA", ddaObject);
ddaObject.add("CustomerId", "String content");
loginObject = new JsonObject();
ddaObject.add("Login", loginObject);
loginObject.add("Password", "String content");
loginObject.add("Username", "String content");
ddaObject.add("NodeID", "String content");
finalJsonString = mainJsonObject.toJsonString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
    JSONObject DDA = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();

    obj1.put("Password", "String Content");
    obj1.put("Username", "String Content");


    obj.put("CustomerId", "String Content");
    obj.put("Login", obj1);
    obj.put("NodeID", "String Content");


    DDA.put("DDA", obj);
```

Comment: There is no array in the sample JSON.

Comment: now check i have just remove the last two line and your JSON object will be present in the DDA object.